# Cargar datos a un formulario Java desde sql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

estoy intentando cargar datos previamentes almacenados en un bd a un formulario en Java

[image: Formulario]

Lo que quiero lograr es que al seleccionar en el combobox algun rut de la lista cargue todos los datos correspondientes (nombre, edad, telefono)

**Mi problema:**
Al momento de seleccionar un rut de la lista, los demas campos no cambian, quedan con los valores correspondientes al primer rut mostrado

Los datos estan bien guardados, ya que tengo una jtable en el cual los muestro, actualizo y elimino

Inserto mi metodo:

```
private void cbrutcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
    String rut = cbrutc.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM  cliente "
            + "WHERE  rut =  '" + rut + "';";

        Conex cn = new Conex();
        ResultSet rs = cn.consulta();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String nm = rs.getString("nombre");
            String ed = rs.getString("edad");
            String tl = rs.getString("telefono");

            tfnombrec.setText(nm);
            tfedadc.setText(ed);
            tftelefonoc.setText(tl);

            tfmontoc.requestFocus();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: debes enlazar un evento del combo que se ejecute cada ves que se cambia de valor(no sé cual),pero le das anticlick al combo y te vas a la opcion de events ahi pruebas cual es que se ejecuta cada ves que se cambia de valor en el combo.

Comment: Necesitas depurar tu programa algo más. ¿Llega a ejecutarse el método? ¿Lanza alguna excepción? ¿Es el SQL que ejecutas correcto (pruébalo en la consola SQL de tu BD)? ¿Devuelve algún resultado? Un par de apuntes: A) Debes cerrar las conexiones y resultsets después de usarlos B) Si solo hay un registro para cada `rut`, un `while` no tiene mucho sentido. Sería mejor un `if`, y si acaso comprobar que no haya registros extra devueltos.

Comment: Si estás utilizando jFrame y eso es un jComboBox puedes utilizar jComboBox.getSelectedItem() y eso te devuelve un Object asi que pasarlo a String que será más fácil para almacenarlo.